# Angular2, 2-way binding, textarea, save to Firebase on Enter

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textarea

I have a textarea control that is bound to a string variable (Angular2). That string variable is set from a Firebase database object (observable using AngularFire). I want to save the textarea value every time the user presses the "Enter" key.

However, when I save the textarea value to the database, the observable fires, updates the variable, and refreshes the textarea. The texarea loses focus. I could re-focus the textarea, but the cursor position would be lost.

How can I prevent the textarea from refreshing after the save? Or, how else can I achieve a seamless user experience?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the observable callback function, I avoided updating the variable that is bound to the textarea control when the form model and database values matched.